# What's going on with this Generic Factory

Tags: c#

I’ve been working on a generic factory recently which bypasses the ‘where’ constraint regarding constructors with parameters, and due to a mistake, I came across something which I don’t quite understand and wondered if anyone would be able to shine some light on it.

The lines of code in question are:

```
ITestInterface myObj = new GenericFactory<ITestInterface>(
    () => (new TestClass("username", "password"))
).CreateObject() as ITestInterface;

ITestInterface myNewObj = new GenericFactory<ITestInterface>(
    (string x, string y) => (new TestClass(x, y))
).CreateObject("username ", " password") as ITestInterface;
```

Both of these lines do the same thing, but I expected the first one to fail.

The code in the factory is as follows:

```
public GenericFactory (Func<T> getNewT)
{
   _getNewObject = getNewT;
}

public GenericFactory(Func<string, string, T> getNewT)
{
   _getNewObjectTwoParams = getNewT;
}

public T CreateObject ()
{
   if (_getNewObject == null)
   {
      return default(T);
   }
   else
   {
       return _getNewObject();
   }
}

public T CreateObject (string username, string password)
{
   if (_getNewObjectTwoParams == null)
   {
      return default(T);
   }
   else
   {
      return _getNewObjectTwoParams(username, password);
   }
}
```

The TestClass has the following constructor:

```
public TestClass (string name, string password)
{
   _name = name;
   _password = password;
}
```

If anyone could shine some light on why the first call to the factory works I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that it wouldn't work? Does `TestClass` not implement `ITestInterface`?

Comment: It does, but I expected that it would fail due to the fact that I was trying to create an object with multiple params in the constructor, hence the overloaded CreateObject method. If I only need the one CreateObject method that's cool, but I was just trying to understand the difference between public GenericFactory (Func<T> getNewT) and GenericFactory(Func<string, string, T> getNewT).

Comment: If you need generic class, with specific constructor constraint, then there is something wrong with your architecture. You should re-think how you use generics. IMO generics should be used with great caution.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you think that Euphoric? Is it not a good idea to have a generic factory class, which allows you to create objects with various different constructors? I'd be happy to hear your views, as I'm always out to learn! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly seems like a lot of overhead for what amounts to:

```
ITestInterface test = new TestClass("username", "password");
```

However, the reason it's working just fine is because you are using the first constructor override:

```
public GenericFactory (Func<T> getNewT)
```

You can pass in any `Func<T>` that returns an instance of `T`. You could do even more inside that function:

```
ITestInterface myObj = new GenericFactory<ITestInterface>(
    () => {
    var username = GetMyUserName();
    var password = GetMyPassword();
    return new TestClass(username, password)
}).CreateObject() as ITestInterface;
```

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but I expected to have to use the second constructor override to allow the creation of an object with two parameters in the constructor. The first call was basically a typo on my part. I didn't think that passing the params directly into the constructor like so TestClass("username", "password") would work, I expected to have to pass the params into the CreateObject method like so: CreateObject("username ", " password"). Thanks for the answer though as it's allowing me to gain a better understanding of how this whole area works.